# How can I convert from Fetch to axios? I get 401 error

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I need to write coding with Axios. But the example of API documentation is with fetch. When I convert Axios I get a 401 error.

Fetch

```
API = "https://api.apilayer.com/exchangerates_data";

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("apikey", API_KEY);
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: "follow",
        headers: myHeaders,
      };
      fetch(`${API}/symbols`, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setCurrenciesData(result.symbols);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((error) => setLoading(false));
    };
```

My friend wrote it with Axios like this and it worked. But when I wrote like this, it gave me same error

```
axios.get(`${API}/symbols&apikey=${API_KEY}`)
```

Comment: If(!) this API accepts the apikey as a GET parameter, then the query string portion of the URL still needs to start with a `?`, and not a `&`.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much. You are right. Axios worked

Comment: If the original `apiKey` is in request headers, why are you trying to put it in the query string?

Comment: @Phil because I could not solve this problem and also tried what you say. But in my friend it worked, that's why

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code!

```js
axios.get({
  baseURL: API,
  url: "/symbols",
  headers: { apikey: API_KEY },
});
```

Here you can check all axios request config available params
[Axios Request Config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config).

Comment: It did not work.  It gave me error ```Cannot GET /[object%20Object]```